# Godot 4: Confusion around changing to a new scene

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I was encountering some weird problems while loading from a scene to another and then back, so to check my sanity I made a minimal reproducible example of the problem.

My minimal example is the following.
Two scenes, that are visually distinguishable, they both have at their root a copy of this script, with "next_scene" set to the other scene.

```
extends Node2D

@export var next_scene: PackedScene = null

func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("space"):
        print(next_scene)
        get_tree().change_scene_to_packed(next_scene)
```

Expected behavior:
I would be able to navigate from one to another back and forth.

Actual behavior:
First load goes well, then going back fails because "next_scene" is said to be null

This happens no matter which scene I start with, proving that it isn't my setup that is wrong.

I tried to implement my own scene manager that would instantiate and queue_free() nodes instead, but I get IDENTICAL behavior.
At this point I'm losing my mind as I've been at it for half a day.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this is a minimal reproducible example of anything. Based solely on this minimal example, `next_scene` *is* `null` and never changes to anything else. If something is setting that to null (or, more precisely, is failing to set it to something meaningful), then the problem is in *that* code, not the code that attempts to load the already-poisoned variable.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo As mentionned in my post, "next_scene" is set to the other scene of the test. Of course this is a point of failure so I checked it many times while testing and it was correct.

Comment: I remember something similar to what you describe, but instead of resulting in one of the scenes having a null reference, resulting in the whole not loading at all because the scenes had cyclic dependency, which was due to Godot loading the PackedScene of the export variable ahead of time. In my projects I store the path of the scene instead (I also use threaded loading when possible, but that is not required).

Comment: @Theraot That was exactly it, I now use a Resource that stores the path to the scene, that way I only have to change it at one place if the scene moves.
Thank you very much.

PS: I'm not sure how the answer system works and whether I should write the answer myself or wait for you to make one.

Comment: @Sigma both work. There is a delay to accepting your own answer. And, of course, the reputation from the upvotes of the answer go to whoever wrote it. I'll post a short answer based on the comments. Then you can decide if you want to post your own or accept it.

Comment: I have expanded the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Godot will load resoruces set to export variables when loading the scene.

This means that while Godot is loading an scene, it would attempt to load the scene from the `PackedScene` set in the export variable it has, and so on.

If these form a dependency cycle - for what I recall - it would lead to the scenes not loading at all.

To avoid this, instead of setting a `PackedScene` set the path to the scene, which then you can `load` (or use thread loading).

---

You said you created a `Resource` where you store the scene path, so that you only need to update said resource (i.e. it is a single source of truth for the scene path).

Which I presume is something like this:

```
class_name SceneReference
extends Resource


@export_file("*.tscn", "*.scn") var scene_path:String
```

We can add to it the functionality of loading the scene:

```
class_name SceneReference
extends Resource


@export_file("*.tscn", "*.scn") var scene_path:String


func get_scene() -> PackedScene:
    # Load the scene and return it
    return load(scene_path)
```

Futhermore, we can ease creating these `Resource`s:

```
@tool
class_name SceneReference
extends Resource


@export_file("*.tscn", "*.scn") var scene_path:String


func get_scene() -> PackedScene:
    # Load the scene and return it
    return load(scene_path)


static func create_for(scene:Node) -> SceneReference:
    if (
        not is_instance_valid(scene)        # We need an existing Node
        or scene.scene_file_path.is_empty() # And it must be the root of a scene
    ):
        # We didn't get the root of a scene, return null
        return null

    # Compute the path to store the SceneReference
    var path := scene.scene_file_path.get_basename() + ".tres"

    # Load the SceneReference from the computed path if possible
    # Create a new SceneReference otherwise
    var resource:SceneReference
    if ResourceLoader.exists(path, "SceneReference"):
        resource = ResourceLoader.load(path, "SceneReference")
    else:
        resource = SceneReference.new()

    # Ensure the path of the SceneReference is set
    resource.scene_path = scene.scene_file_path

    if Engine.is_editor_hint():
        # Ensure it is saved at the computed path
        ResourceSaver.save(resource, path, ResourceSaver.FLAG_CHANGE_PATH)

        # Ensure it is up to date in Godot's cache
        resource.take_over_path(path)

    # Return the SceneReference
    return resource
```

I have decided I want a method that takes the path (thus I have also added a check in case the path does not exist):

```
@tool
class_name SceneReference
extends Resource


@export_file("*.tscn", "*.scn") var scene_path:String


func get_scene() -> PackedScene:
    # Load the scene and return it
    return load(scene_path)


static func create_for(scene:Node) -> SceneReference:
    if not is_instance_valid(scene):
        # We didn't get a node
        return null

    return create_for_path(scene.scene_file_path)


static func create_for_path(scene_file_path:String) -> SceneReference:
    if scene_file_path.is_empty() or not FileAccess.file_exists(scene_file_path):
        # We didn't get a scene file path
        return null

    # Compute the path to store the SceneReference
    var path := scene_file_path.get_basename() + ".tres"

    # Load the SceneReference from the computed path if possible
    # Create a new SceneReference otherwise
    var resource:SceneReference
    if ResourceLoader.exists(path, "SceneReference"):
        resource = ResourceLoader.load(path, "SceneReference")
    else:
        resource = SceneReference.new()

    # Ensure the path of the SceneReference is set
    resource.scene_path = scene_file_path

    if Engine.is_editor_hint():
        # Ensure it is saved at the computed path
        ResourceSaver.save(resource, path, ResourceSaver.FLAG_CHANGE_PATH)

        # Ensure it is up to date in Godot's cache
        resource.take_over_path(path)

    # Return the SceneReference
    return resource
```

That is all too great, but in practice it seems too easy modify the scene path when we do not intent to.

At first, I managed to store the path but not allow editing it...

But if the mechanism we use to create the `SceneReference` puts gives it the name of the scene and stores it in the same path, we do not need to store the path at all.

This also eases moving the `SceneReference` file and the scene to a difference path without the need of editing the `SceneReference`. In fact, there won't be anything stored in the `SceneReference`:

```
@tool
class_name SceneReference
extends Resource


signal load_progress(load_percentage:float)
signal loaded(scene:PackedScene)


var scene_path:String:
    get:
        return resource_path.get_basename()
    set(_mod_value):
        return


func get_scene() -> PackedScene:
    # Load the scene and return it
    return load(scene_path)


static func create_for(scene:Node) -> SceneReference:
    if not is_instance_valid(scene):
        # We didn't get a node
        return null

    return create_for_path(scene.scene_file_path)


static func create_for_path(scene_file_path:String) -> SceneReference:
    if scene_file_path.is_empty() or not ResourceLoader.exists(scene_file_path, "PackedScene"):
        # We didn't get a scene file path
        return null

    # Compute the path to store the SceneReference
    var path := scene_file_path + ".tres"

    # Load the SceneReference from the computed path if possible
    # Create a new SceneReference otherwise
    var resource:SceneReference
    if ResourceLoader.exists(path, "SceneReference"):
        resource = ResourceLoader.load(path, "SceneReference")
    else:
        resource = SceneReference.new()

    if Engine.is_editor_hint():
        # Ensure it is saved at the computed path
        ResourceSaver.save(resource, path, ResourceSaver.FLAG_CHANGE_PATH)

        # Ensure it is up to date in Godot's cache
        resource.take_over_path(path)

    # Return the SceneReference
    return resource
```

---

Speaking of the mechanism to create them, you can use it form the script of the scenes like this:

```
@tool

func _ready() -> void:
    SceneReference.create_for(self)
```

Or you could create a script you add to a node that does this for the scene root:

```
@tool

func _ready() -> void:
    SceneReference.create_for(owner)
```

I decided to give it a name, and let it work both ways:

```
@tool
class_name SceneReferenciable
extends Node


func _ready() -> void:
    SceneReference.create_for(owner if scene_file_path.is_empty() else self)
```

---

We can go further and add threaded loading to `SceneReference`:

```
@tool
class_name SceneReference
extends Resource


signal load_progress(load_percentage:float)
signal loaded(scene:PackedScene)


var scene_path:String:
    get:
        return resource_path.get_basename()
    set(_mod_value):
        return


var load_percentage:float:
    set(mod_value):
        if load_percentage == mod_value:
            return

        load_percentage = mod_value
        # The percentage changed, emit the signal
        load_progress.emit(load_percentage)


var packed_scene:PackedScene:
    get:
        if typeof(_state) == TYPE_OBJECT:
            return _state as PackedScene

        return null
    set(_mod_value):
        return


var error:Error = OK

var _state:Variant = null


func begin_load() -> void:
    if Engine.is_editor_hint():
        # We do not load in the editor
        return

    match typeof(_state):
        TYPE_OBJECT:
            var result:PackedScene = _state
            if is_instance_valid(result):
                # It was loaded previously
                emit_signal.call_deferred("loaded", result)
                return
        TYPE_INT:
            # It already failed to load
            emit_signal.call_deferred("loaded", null)
            return
        TYPE_NIL:
            # Load not started yet
            _load()


func _load() -> void:
    var result:Variant = _request()
    if typeof(result) == TYPE_FLOAT:
        # Loading, set the percentage
        load_percentage = result

        # We will check again later
        _load.call_deferred()
    else:
        # Done loading
        load_percentage = 1.0

        # try to get the result
        var _packed_scene := result as PackedScene
        if is_instance_valid(_packed_scene):
            # We got a valid result
            emit_signal.call_deferred("loaded", _packed_scene)
        else:
            # We got an error
            if typeof(result) == TYPE_INT:
                error = result
            else:
                error = FAILED

            emit_signal.call_deferred("loaded", null)


func _request() -> Variant:
    match typeof(_state):
        TYPE_NIL:
            # Not started
            if not ResourceLoader.exists(scene_path, "PackedScene"):
                # Failed
                _state = ERR_DOES_NOT_EXIST
                return ERR_DOES_NOT_EXIST

            var err := ResourceLoader.load_threaded_request(scene_path, "PackedScene")
            if OK != err:
                # Failed
                _state = err
                return err
            else:
                # Loading
                _state = 0.0
                return 0.0
        TYPE_OBJECT:
            # Succeeded
            var state_as_resource := _state as PackedScene
            if is_instance_valid(state_as_resource):
                return state_as_resource
            else:
                return FAILED
        TYPE_INT:
            # Failed, return error code
            return _state
        TYPE_FLOAT:
            # Loading
            var state_as_float:float = _state
            var progress:Array[float] = []
            var status := ResourceLoader.load_threaded_get_status(scene_path, progress)
            if status == ResourceLoader.THREAD_LOAD_LOADED:
                # Succeeded
                var result := ResourceLoader.load_threaded_get(scene_path)
                _state = result
                return result
            elif status == ResourceLoader.THREAD_LOAD_FAILED:
                # Failed
                _state = FAILED
                return FAILED
            else:
                # Loading
                var percentage := maxf(progress[0], state_as_float)
                _state = percentage
                return percentage
        _:
            return FAILED


static func create_for(scene:Node) -> SceneReference:
    if not is_instance_valid(scene):
        # We didn't get a node
        return null

    return create_for_path(scene.scene_file_path)


static func create_for_path(scene_file_path:String) -> SceneReference:
    if scene_file_path.is_empty() or not ResourceLoader.exists(scene_file_path, "PackedScene"):
        # We didn't get a scene file path
        return null

    # Compute the path to store the SceneReference
    var path := scene_file_path + ".tres"

    # Load the SceneReference from the computed path if possible
    # Create a new SceneReference otherwise
    var resource:SceneReference
    if ResourceLoader.exists(path, "SceneReference"):
        resource = ResourceLoader.load(path, "SceneReference")
    else:
        resource = SceneReference.new()

    if Engine.is_editor_hint():
        # Ensure it is saved at the computed path
        ResourceSaver.save(resource, path, ResourceSaver.FLAG_CHANGE_PATH)

        # Ensure it is up to date in Godot's cache
        resource.take_over_path(path)

    # Return the SceneReference
    return resource
```

Note: I emit the signal using a `call_deferred` and also emit it when the load fails for the benefit of the code consuming it, which could be like this:

```
@export var scene_reference:SceneReference

func _ready() -> void:
    scene_reference.begin_load()
    var scene:PackedScene = await scene_reference.loaded
    prints(scene)
```

Using `call_deferred` I ensure the signal happens after returning, and by emiting it even if the load failed I ensure to not have the script awaiting forever.

You could, of course, connect to the signals if you prefer... In which case be aware that `loaded` might be emited multiple times (I recommend using the flag `CONNECT_ONE_SHOT`).