# File picker in Godot

Tags: c#, .net, godot, godot4

I can't find a structure representing a file in Godot to use in the editor

I want to add a property to my Node
something like:

```
[GlobalClass]
public partial class MyObj : Node2D
{
    [Export] public File myFile;

...
```

It should be possible to pick a file (a file location) and assign it to that variable, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No structure. `String`. For example:

```
[Export(PropertyHint.File)]
public string GameFile { get; set; }
```

Source: [Strings as paths](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_exports.html#strings-as-paths)

---

From comments, it seems you want a `Resource`, when in Godot 4, you should be able export that directly. The documentation has the next couple examples.

Accept any `Resource`:

```
[Export]
private Resource Resource;
```

Accept only `AnimationNode`:

```
[Export]
private AnimationNode Resource;
```

See [Resources](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_exports.html#resources). *It is on the same page as the linked above, but further down.*

I want to clarify that this works with any built-in resource, for example if you want a scene, you can do this:

```
[Export]
private PackedScene Resource;
```

And if you create a new class that extends from `Resource` it should work with that class too. For example for `MyResource` you do this:

```
[Export]
private MyResource Resource;
```

Comment: I see, it's a solution, but i think there is no reliable solution to input resource paths (the problem, in this case, is that there is no actual ""linking" between the string path and the resource itself, i can't move or change the resource name without having to manually update the string referencing it)

Comment: @user8322140 You didn't say you wanted a resource. Expanded answer.

Comment: Yeah i didn't explain the question clearly, i don't need a Resource (which is loaded once the object gets created), but a reference to it (so its file path), for instantiating it from code whenever i want (or use background workers to do so, like loading a big scene etc...)

Comment: @user8322140 There is no build-in that does both tracking the file if it moves and also is strongly typed, without loading ahead of time... But you might be able to create a `Resource` that has the logic to load another resource, and workaround saving the path, see my [SceneReference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77826371/402022).

Comment: I saw, it's a well documented solution, i'll try to implement something similar. I suggest you to open an Issue of GitHub with that, it might be useful to anyone to have something like that built-in in the engine!